# How to get random index of minimum values from an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, random

I've an array like this:

```php
$a[0] = 2;
$a[1] = 7;
$a[2] = 5;
$a[3] = 2;
$a[4] = 2;
$a[5] = 3;
```

I want to get random index of only minimum values in this array.
In above array the function should return either 0 or 3 or 4 because *2* is the only minimum value in this array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php


$a = [];
$a[0] = 2;
$a[1] = 7;
$a[2] = 5;
$a[3] = 2;
$a[4] = 2;
$a[5] = 3;


$min_val = min($a);

$min_indexes = [];
foreach($a as $i => $val){
    if($val == $min_val) $min_indexes[] = $i;
}

print_r($min_indexes);
echo $min_indexes[rand(0,count($min_indexes)-1)];
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/PXcq4

First, get the [min](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.min.php) value from the array. Now, collect all indexes that have this min value. Now, generate  random number from the indexes of the filtered collection using [rand()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php).

Answer (score 1):

You can `array_keys` with `array_flip`, `array_rand`, `min` functions

```
echo array_rand(array_flip(array_keys ($a, min($a))));
```

Live example:- https://3v4l.org/b4La1